# Dynamics AX 2012 - Adding Tables to Database Logging Selection List

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Is it possible to add tables to the `Database Logging` selection listing in AX 2012? If yes, is it possible to select which category each table appears in?

**System Administration > Database > Database log setup > New**

When I select `Show all tables`, some tables still do not appear. The tables do not appear in the `Not specified` category either.

We need to log additional AX built parameter tables as well developer built tables. The developer tables were built in the Development Workspace so we have access to all the Table properties.

[image: DatabaseLogggingList]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add new button to the form with custom code

[image: AddByTableName]

```cs
void clicked()
{
    TableId promptTableId;

    Dialog d;
    DialogField df;

    void createLine(DatabaseLogType logType)
    {
        DatabaseLog.logTable = promptTableId;
        DatabaseLog.LogType = logType;

        DatabaseLog.insert();
    }

    d = new Dialog("Enter table name");
    df = d.addField(extendedTypeStr(TableName));
    d.parmIsModal(true);

    if (d.run())
    {
        promptTableId = tableName2id(df.value());
        if (!promptTableId)
        {
             throw error(strFmt("Table %1 does not exists", df.value()));
        }

        ttsBegin;
        createLine(DatabaseLogType::Insert);
        createLine(DatabaseLogType::Update);
        createLine(DatabaseLogType::Delete);
        ttsCommit;

        SysFlushDatabaseLogSetup::main();

        info(strFmt("For table %1 (%2) records are created: %3, %4, %5."
            , tableId2name(promptTableId)
            , tableId2pname(promptTableId)
            , DatabaseLogType::Insert
            , DatabaseLogType::Update
            , DatabaseLogType::Delete
        ));
    }

    super();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `buildTableTree` in form `SysDatabaseLogWizard` seems to be a good place to start looking for answers to your questions:

> Is it possible to add tables to the Database Logging selection listing
>   in AX 2012?

Yes, it is possible.

> If yes, is it possible to select which category each table appears in?

Yes, you have to modify the configuration key of the table to change the category. Please note that the root configuration key is used as category, so check first if the configuration key of the table has a parent key (e.g. table `CommissionCustomerGroup` has configuration key `Commission` which has configuration key `LogisticsBasic` as parent key, therefore the table appears in category Trade).

Please note that changing the configuration key can have additional consequences and I would not recommend to do it merely to change the category of the database logging selection.

Regarding your observation that some tables are not listed, there are several conditions that must be fulfilled so that a table gets listed:

- must be enabled (`dictTable.enabled()`, I'm guessing that means the configuration key is enabled)
- has table group main or option "Show all tables" is enabled or the table is already set up for logging
- the table is neither table `SysDataBaseLog` nor `SysUserLog`
- the table is not a temporary table
- the table is not a map
- a `DictTable` instance can be created for the table id

If your missing tables fulfill those conditions, I suggest debugging method `buildTableTree` of form `SysDatabaseLogWizard` to find out why a table is not added to the tree control.

Comment: Thank you for the information, the details were very handy completing my task.